# How can I trigger parent component rerendering from the child?

Tags: reactjs

I'm total newbie in react and have to write a book library SPA. My project so far has All books page which loads all books. Each book has "More" button which leads to the single book with the given bookid. The single book renders all its reviews. Each review has like, dislike, edit, delete functionalities (separate imported components). So basically the single Book component has the Single Review component in itself and the Single Review component has in itself all the  like/dislike/edit review components functionalities.  Like Review, Dislike Review Update Review are all separate components imported in Single Review. How can I trigger the single Book to rerender when for example I click on the like review button? The Like component has in itself one fetch request sending the data to the server and renders the button triggering this request. As you may probably have guessed it everything works ok but I always have to refresh the page manually to see the result of the request. So far I haven't come up of reliable way to trigger the parent Single Book to rerender.

P.S I'm trying to do all this with functional programming not OOP.

Comment: Can you provide your component structure?

Comment: I suggest you to learn react before anything, you clearly don't know how it works. Then if you have problems, come back here. There are a lot of complete lessons online. Have fun

Comment: yagizhan.avci of course just don't know what will be the best way to do this? Some kind of diagram?

BloodyMonkey I know that but unfortunately this is what I have been thought for 3 weeks. I will appreciate if you can tell me which fundamental principles I break. Thanks.